# Why integer representation of character 'o' is 63 in C?

Tags: c

If I do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
        int test_int = 'o' - '0';
        printf("%d", test_in);
}
```

I will see 63 as output.

Why is that? If I look at the ASCII table, in position 63, I see the character '?'.

What am I missing here? What is my misunderstanding?

I guess my confusion is that I have read that in order to get the Integer representation of a character, you need to substract '0'.

Comment: The value of `'0'`, the character, is not `0`.

Comment: `printf("%d\n", 'o');` will print 111 as expected.

Comment: Why did you subtract `'0'` from it???

Comment: What I would like to know is the correct numerical value for `'o'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I guess my confusion is that I have read that in order to get the Integer representation of a character, you need to substract '0'.

No, that is valid only for numeric characters `'0'` to `'9'`. And that rule applies simply because characters `'0'` to `'9'` are in a sequence in [ASCII table](http://www.ascii-code.com/). So when you subtract `'0'` from any numeric character you get the integer represented by that character.

Comment: It doesn't really matter what character set is used. A conforming C implementation is required to have the digit characters in a contiguous sequence from `'0'` to `'9'`.

Answer (score 4):

Anything with in the single quotes(`' '`) is treated as a character constants.

```
int test_int = 'o' - '0';
```

If you use `' '` to represent any character or integer, that is treated as a character constant.

Where 'o' is a character `o`, '0' is a integer `0`. But here both are treated as a character constants it will take ascii value of the respective constants! Ascii value of `o` is 111 and ascii of `0` is 48.

So 111-48 =63

Answer (score 1):

You are not printing the value of character `'o'`, but the result of `'o'-'0'` (and `'0'`'s value is 48)...

Comment: So, when why is it said that to find the integer representation of a character, the subtraction ``'character' - '0'`` has to be done. What does that mean?

Comment: That expression is used to get the _numerical_ value of a digit, e.g. `'7' - '0' == 7`. It doesn't work for other characters (not even hexadecimal digits) and it works only because the digits occupy a contiguous space in ASCII. You will see this expression most often in code that parses a string for a number.

Comment: A character by itself is already a number - i.e. (on common platforms, for characters in range 0-127) a character *is* its ASCII code. The `-'0'` thing is used instead when you want to convert a *digit* expressed as a `char` to the corresponding number. The trick works because `'0'`-`'9'` are guaranteed by the standard to be consecutive in the character set.

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting `'0'` from characters is only useful for converting a digit **character** into its value, e.g. converting the **character** `'4'` (which often has the value 0x34, or 52 in decimal) into the value 4. It really isn't useful to subtract it from any other character.

```
'4' != 4
```

But

```
'4' - '0' == 4
```

C guarantees that digit characters have contiguous values, so that's why the “trick” works.

Answer (score 0):

```
int test_int = 'o' - '0';
```

Here character `o` has ASCII value `111` and `0` has ASCII value value `48`.
 which means

```
int test_int = 111 - 48;
```

i.e
`test_int = 63;`

```
printf("%d", test_int); //it will print 63
```

If you want to print `?`,then use

```
printf("%c", test_int);
```